# Delete changeset or just fix it on next commit?

Tags: svn

I develop an open source project on codeplex.com. I committed some wrong changesets to codeplex.com and I can not delete them but I know that I can delete entire project.

For a good open source project, should I face the headache of deleting the project or just fix it in next commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Planting errors is (I wanted to say "normal", but that's a too positive characteristic...) typical - just fix in a separate commit, provide an appropriate commit message (like "fix error planted in revision N") and move on.

The project I work on is not open source, bu the code is of very high quality. Still I sometimes find errors that have been there for years (really!). Do I reset the entire repository because of that? Surely not. Just fix and move on.

Comment: I think that already nobody doesn't care old changesets, they just care about latest version, right ?

Comment: @Freshblood: Most of the time - yes. Sometimes they would like to know "why this strange code is here" and they will use "blame". Sometimes they will want to find what has changed during some period of time. So history is important, don't think it's useless and don't think people won't look into it, but I can hardly imagine a situation where deleting all history for the sake of in fact hinding one bad commit is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how bad the damage is. If it is e.g. photos you would rather the world not see, then delete the changeset (if codeplex.com lets you `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin import`, you can delete the changeset that way, without deleting the whole project.)

If the changeset just has misspelled words, or buggy code, or something, just fix it with the next check-in. You'll doubtless make mistakes in the future, so you might as well get used to it now. :)